# How to use Lambda with Collectors in older version of Android?

Tags: android, lambda

I'm trying to use Java 8 features especially Lambda expressions in my android app to manipulate a huge list of data like this:

```
List<CustomerListModel> filteredList = dataModel.parallelStream()                                                         
                                                .filter(c -> c.getDistance() < 500 )                                                             
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Collectors methods needs Api 24 or higher, but current min is 15. How can I use Lambda in older versions?

Comment: You can use Retrolambda or use new Jack toolchain for Lambda expressions and method references .. however the Streams API you can't use below SDK 24

Comment: Consider kotlin